# LIN Protocol Transceiver Behaviour during the GotoSleep Command

Tags: microcontroller, can-bus, communication-protocol

I am using LIN Protocol for Parking Brake functionality. baud rate : 10.4Kbps

1)  I am sending the go to sleep command in $3C frame, after 50ms sending 0v to NSLP to put LIN Transceiver into sleep Mode but it is taking 9s for
INHIBIT pin to go low  from the trigger of $3C Frame. My understanding is once the NSLP goes to Zero, immediately INH Should go to low.

```
1) Is this the correct behaviour?
2) if some presses the Button (LIN Slave) during the 9s how the behaviour will be ?
3) Will LIN Slave send the wakeup pattern?
4) how INH pin will behave since it is already high?
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are speaking about LIN transciever chip, you must specify its partnumber.
For example, I suggest that you are using NXP's TJA1020 http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TJA1020.pdf

It have INH output pin with two states: active high, when chip in non-sleep mode, and high-impedance (Z-state), when chip in sleep mode.

Also, I suggest that there is no load on INH pin.

So, when you turn on sleep mode, INH discarged only through your multimeter (scope?), and it takes few seconds.